# Group Columns based on Category and date and return latest category and corresponding results for each category in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Desired Input:

```
 emp id | appointment_id | appointment_type | assessment_date | Result_id | Res_Date 
 100115 | 77382          | HAEC1            | 06.10.2009      | 1234      | 07.10.2009
 100115 | 77890          | HAEC1            | 07.10.2009      | 1256      | 12.10.2009
 100115 | 77890          | HAEC1            | 07.10.2009      | 1156      | 12.10.2009
 100115 | 77111          | HAEC1            | 07.10.2015      | 1296      | 12.10.2015
 100115 | 77222          | HAEC1            | 09.10.2016      | 1246      | 12.10.2016
 100115 | 77222          | HAEC1            | 09.10.2016      | 1346      | 12.10.2016
 100115 | 77222          | HAEC1            | 09.10.2016      | 1446      | 12.10.2016
 100115 | 77333          | HAB1             |09.10.2016       |1246       | 12.10.2016
 100115 | 77444          | HAC1             | 09.10.2016      | 1246      | 12.10.2016
 100115 | -77555         | HAC3             | 09.10.2016      | 1246      | 12.10.2016
```

And the desired output is

```
emp id | appointment_id| appointment_type| assessment_date|Result_id| Res_Date
100115 |-77222         |HAEC1            |09.10.2016|     1246      |12.10.2016|
100115 |-77222         |HAEC1            |09.10.2016|     1346      |12.10.2016|
100115 |-77222         |HAEC1            |09.10.2016|     1446      |12.10.2016|
100115 |-77333         |HAB1             |09.10.2016|     1246      |12.10.2016|
100115 |-77444         |HAC1             |09.10.2016|     1246      |12.10.2016|
100115 |-77555         |HAC3             |09.10.2016|     1246      |12.10.2016|
```

Comment: What are the business rules which turn the input data into the desired result set?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post your code, explaining the logic you need; if not, please do some effort before asking for help

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the filter you want is based on the value of `assessment_date` and that the negative value for all the `appointment_id` is not a typo:

```
select emp id
       , case when appointment_id > 0 then
                   appointment_id * -1 
               else appointment_id 
        end as appointment_id 
      , appointment_type
      , assessment_date
      , Result_id
      , Res_Date
from your_table
where assessment_date > sysdate
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your response@APC :). Really appreciate. I found a solution and delivered the query, by added a subquery in where clause to retrieve latest appointments grouping by category.

Comment: And "-" is not typo, the actual data has -